# Retrieve profile attributes from _Subscribers using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%[ 

set @skey= "abc@test.com" 
set @allSubRows = LookupRows("_Subscribers","SubscriberKey",@skey) 

SET @sub_row = ROW(@allSubRows,1)
SET @subAtts = FIELD(@sub_row,"Status")

]%%
```

working fine,

but when i try to access profile attributes :
First_name, Last_name
not working

tried various options not working, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sending to a List or a Data Extension?

Answer (score 2):

There are no profile attributes in the [**_Subscribers**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/) data view.

If you're working with a Enterprise 2.0 account, they'll be in [**_EnterpriseAttributes**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_enterpriseattribute/), which is accessible via SubscriberID (`%%subscriberid%%`).